# sql positional parameters on the left side of an equals sign

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, pg

Trying to do a sql update on postgres 9.  Notice the $1 on the left side of the equals sign.  That will be the name of a column in a table that is passed in.  When I hard code a column name the update works perfectly.  But when I try and pass the column in as a parameter ($1), the update fails.  Why, and how do I fix this?

```
pg.connect(connectionString,function (err, client) {
    client.query("UPDATE people SET $1 = $2 WHERE pin = $3 RETURNING pin",
      [param1, param2, param3], function(err, result){
        if(err) {
            console.log("Error updating data: ", err);
            res.send(false);
        }else{
          res.send(true);
        }
      });
  });
```

Comment: You can think of column names sort of like variable names in other languages so allowing placeholders for them would be akin to using `eval` so it generally isn't allowed. Check your database interface's documentation for a "quote identifier" or "escape identifier" function, use that function to properly quote `param1` and using string concatenation to get the quoted value into your SQL. Note that identifiers (such as table or column names) have different quoting rules than values so be sure to use the right quoting function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`client.query` uses prepared statement internally so that your query is executed in two SQL statements:

```
PREPARE some_generated_name AS
UPDATE people SET $1 = $2 WHERE pin = $3 RETURNING pin;

EXECUTE some_generated_name('data1', 'data2', 'data3');
```

This is a reasonable approach if you want to execute the same query many times. `PREPARE` tells PostgreSQL to parse and plan the query ahead because a lot of `EXECUTE` statements are coming and he should be ready for it.

Then PostgreSQL do everything he can ahead of time, this includes parsing and planning. Parsing means that he syntactically validates the query and "understand" it, planning means that he tries to anticipate which operation is going to be executed on which table.

This is the part where PostgreSQL tries to transform the declarative SQL to a procedural set of instructions like "fetch this particular table", "update this column in this table where this column match this variable", ... (in practice this system is much more complex but really interesting)

The problem is that parsing is not possible with a dynamic column name so PostgreSQL refuses to `PREPARE`your query.

You should not use column variables, you must use fixed named columns, as you have a limited number of well known columns, use a white-list to validate the user inputs and use simple string concatenation.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying.  The below works.  Is it ok?  The column still isn't hardcoded, but it's no longer being passed as a parameter.  Is this a security risk?
 
`pg.connect(connectionString,function (err, client) {
    client.query("UPDATE people 
    SET param1 = $1 WHERE pin = $2 RETURNING pin",
      [param2, param3], 
    ...`

Comment: Looks like this will make me vulnerable to SQL injection?

Comment: It will if you don't filter param1.

Comment: You know your schema columns, check that param1 exists in a pre-defined list of column names and you won't have any sql injections.